# CakePHP : Search date from form helper

Tags: cakephp, date-format, cakephp-2.3

I use form helpers to show drop down select date. My problem is, i can't compare date from ms sql with form data.

My View :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('collect_date', array('label' => 'Collect Date','type'=>'date','dateFormat'=> 'DMY','minYear' => date('Y'),'maxYear' => date('Y')+1));?>
```

My Controller

```
$status =array(0,2,4);
$find_date = $this->data['Transaction']['collect_date'];
$field = array('Transaction.status','Catalogue.title', 'Catalogue.author', 'Catalogue.isbn', 'Location.rack');
$condition = array('OR' => array('AND' =>array('Transaction.return_date <'=> $find_date,'Transaction.status '=> '3'),array('Transaction.status'=> $status)));
$data = $this->Catalogue->Transaction->find('count',array('fields' => $field,'conditions'=>$condition,'order'=>array('Transaction.id desc') )); 
$this->set('Found', $data);
```

And the sql dump

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [count] FROM [transactions] AS [Transaction]
LEFT JOIN [catalogues] AS [Catalogue] ON ([Transaction].[catalogue_id] = [Catalogue].[id]) 
LEFT JOIN [users] AS [User] ON ([Transaction].[user_id] = [User].[id]) 
WHERE (((([Transaction].[return_date] < ('01', '09', 2013)) 
AND ([Transaction].[status] = 3))) OR ([Transaction].[status] IN (0, 2, 4)))
```

As you can see the date format ('01', '09', 2013). But when try to convert use this

```
'Transaction.return_date <'=> date('Y-m-d', strtotime($find_date))
```

it show error:

```
Warning (2): strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [APP\Controller\CataloguesController.php, line 66]
```

and the sql show:

```
[Transaction].[return_date] < '1970-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y',  implode('/', $find_date));
'Transaction.return_date <'=> $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Edit:

I think the way its meant to be 'flattened' is with

```
$this->Model->deconstruct('find_date', $find_date);
```

However, last time i tried to use this, i couldn't get it to work properly, so i went with the above.
http://api21.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modeldeconstruct

Comment: @Eion: I made a PR to use the deconstruct as you suggest: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/842 - but the other didnt quite like it ;) Anyway, to make deconstruct work here, you would need to add the field to the schema of the model.

Comment: I liked the idea of just having a method to use deconstruct it.  I'm using mongo atm and I don't like the idea of having to specify my schema, since it interferes with what will be saved and ruins some of mongos flexibility.

Comment: well, my PR was both the method and more automagic. maybe, if its only the method it might be worth adding to the core?

Comment: Probably if it was added to CakeTime? CakeTime::deconstruct( $format, $array ) Since the form helper makes it that way, there should definitely be a way of extracting it

Answer (score 0):

Try converting return date using UNIX_TIMESTAMP in sql query and then comparing it with
strtotime($find_date).